# Blazor saying that it is missing assembly or reference for Interface

Tags: c#, class, blazor, blazor-server-side, inject

I get this error:
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IReimbursementTravelRcptService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I declare my class like this:

```
namespace Expense_Reimbursement.Services {
    public interface IReimbursementTravelRcptService
    {

    }

    public class ReimbursementTravelRcptService : IReimbursementTravelRcptService
    {
       
    } }
```

I have this in the Startup.cs in ConfigureServices:
services.AddScoped<IReimbursementTravelRcptService, ReimbursementTravelRcptService>();

But when I try to inject it it gives the error above:
@inject IReimbursementTravelRcptService _irtsrService;

I feel like I forgot something simple but I do not know what I am missing.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Which file is causing this compiler error? If it's Startup.cs, can you double check to see that the namespace Expense_Reimbursement.Services is included at the top of the file?

Comment: Everything in the startup.cs is fine it finds the class and the interface.  The problem is in the component it says in there only it can't find the reference even though I have "@using Expense_Reimbursement.Services" in it AND it can find other classes from there just fine.

Comment: Create and post a [mre]